# Paypal DPRA disable for this merchant message for recurring payment

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I create test account on https://developer.paypal.com  and in test account i set country as USA and account type is business. i have to configured recurring payment. but i still got this error

```
 [ERRORS] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [L_ERRORCODE] => 11586
                [L_SHORTMESSAGE] => DPRP is disabled.
                [L_LONGMESSAGE] => DPRP is disabled for this merchant.
                [L_SEVERITYCODE] => Error
            )

    )
```

The all article is too old. and paypal environment is changed. please tell me how i enable DPRP .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not able to enable this on your account, if you can provide me with the email address of your test sandbox seller account, or your merchant ID for this account I can try to enable this on your account from my end.

Comment: can i send this on ur email ? what is ur email

Comment: You can file a ticket with us via https://paypal.com/mts/ - let us know the ticket# here and we'll take care of it for you.

Comment: my ticket number is  Reference #130514-000040

Comment: Your ticket has been picked up and is currently being worked by technical support.

Comment: Please also help me to enable DRPA. Ticket ID : #140625-000085

Answer (score 1):

DirectPayment Recurring Payments(DPRA). It's an feature that you have to get enabled on your PayPal account.

Comment: but from where? i didnt find the link

Comment: log in your paypal account. go to product and services tab and check bottom of the page you will find recurring payments.
link:-https://www.paypal.com/in/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/xcl/rec/subscr-intro

Comment: here i found the button generation code but i have to take payment on my site. can i still enable this feature?

Comment: hi @DesertP , i have got an url that might help you..
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/direct-payment/ht_dp-recurringPaymentProfile-curl-etc/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29905/discussion-between-desert-p-and-rajeev-ranjan)